# Why are the "Use" declaration lines of code disappearing?! Magento2

Tags: php, magento2.3

I am adding a new PHP file to an existing Controllers folder. I am trying to insert the same "use" declarations into my new file as in the other existing controller files within this same folder.
When I try to copy over the use declarations into my file and then press save the "use" declaration code disappears!

Here's the use statements I am trying to insert that disappears when I hit save:

```
use \Mobileplans\Api\Data\VirtualnumbersInterface;
use \Mobileplans\Api\VirtualnumbersRepositoryInterface as VirtualnumbersRepository;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
```

The only use declaration code block that saves to this new file without disappearing is:

```
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause for the use statements disappearing was that my IDE was cleaning out any use statements that were not being used in my file.
Once I added code that utilized the class I was trying to use, the use statement stopped disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

Everything outside of a pair of opening and closing tags is ignored by the PHP parser which allows PHP files to have mixed content. This allows PHP to be embedded in HTML documents.
[blog](https://moviesinfi.com/)